# What is the "azure-cli-{timestamp}" user?

Tags: azure

I just noticed under the IAM tab for each VM in Azure that there is an `azure-cli-{timestamp_here}` user tied to it.

I was unable to find information on why, or when, these users are created. They were definitely not explicitly created and I have security concerns.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a user, is should be a service principal(Type is App).  You should view it like below:

[image]

When you(or other) use Azure CLi 2.0 to create a service principal and give `Contributor` role on subscription level. You will see this. More information please check this [link:Get started with Role-Based Access Control in the Azure portal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is).

More information about Azure CLi 2.0 to create sp you could check this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

**In the older document, the example is `az ad sp create-for-rbac`, if you don't specify the name, the default name is `azure-cli-{timestamp_here}`.**

Comment: If my answer helps, please don't forget to accept it as an answer. Also, you have question about this, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, any update about this?

Answer (score 0):

Number of areas this should be logged in.

Firstly, if this is a security concern, would recommend opening up a Microsoft Support case to help investigate this IAM object.

It's possible that this could be a service principal (azure-cli-) which was created in the past. If you go to the app registration link below, do you see any application with the same name?

Couple of areas for checking audit logs as well, user specific and global azure active directory wide.

[Azure Active Directory - App registrations](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps)

[Azure Active Directory - Users - Audit logs](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UsersManagementMenuBlade/Audit)

[Azure Active Directory - Audit logs](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Audit)